# Symbolic Toolbox matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm working on an algorithm of optimal control. my program should do calculation on symbolic functions. I'm looking for an optimal([z,u]:[solution,Control signal]) solution for my problem. I tried the first iteration: i have calculated u and z, but when i'm trying to calculate u for the next iteration i have a problem on 'lambda expression'.the problem is that matlab send me an error msg that i can't understand. here is the error msg:

> ????? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
>
> Error in ==> sym.int at 56
>          r = mupadmex('mllib::intdef',f.s,x.s,a.s,b.s);

here is the code:

```
clc;clear all;
syms x t k;
b=0.53;T=2;
tol=0.0001;
phi=sqrt(2)*sin(k*pi*x);
alphax=x^2*(x-1)^2;
betax=-2*x*(x-1);
phi1=sqrt(2)*sin(k*pi*b);

%% initialisation de lambda et z
lambda_pr=x;
z_pr=-1*x*(x-1);
%%iteration1
for m=1:10 
% use 10 iteration just for test, it can be more 
% in the second iteration i got the error here
prim=int(phi*lambda_pr,x,0,1);
u=-symsum(((exp((-k^2*pi^2)*(T-t))*phi1)*prim),k,1,10);

z_max=lambda_pr + z_pr-alphax;
z_min=lambda_pr + z_pr-betax;
z_max=matlabFunction(-1*z_max);%convert to matlab function 
z_min=matlabFunction(z_min);   %convert to matlab function

[xMin, minValue] = fminbnd(z_min, 0, 1);
[xMax, maxValue] = fminbnd(z_max, 0, 1);

if maxValue<0
    z_new=alphax;
elseif minValue>0
    z_new=betax;
else
    z_new=z;
end
%ecart
ecart=(z_new-z_pr)^2;    
err=double((int(ecart,0,1))^(0.5))


if err>tol
    %here where i have the problem
    primt=int(exp((-k^2*pi^2)*(2-t))*u,t,0,2));
      lambda_pr = lambda_pr + symsum(primt,k,1,10)-z_new;
      z_pr=z_new;

end
end
```

Comment: The code you posted contains one syntax error. I corrected it and then ran your code, and it works on my computer. What is the problem? Can you specify which matlab version are you using?

Comment: @Cebri : I'm using MATLAB 7.10.0(R2010a)

Comment: Also works for me, on MATLAB R2015a.